# Starting concourse worker with garden dns proxy enable flag errors

Tags: dns, concourse

I'm attempting to start concourse worker with --garden-dns-proxy-enable flag in hope of getting past some git authentication errors that I read could be as a result of [DNS issues](https://tutorials.technology/tutorials/32-concourse-continous-build-and-deploy-configuration.html#appendix)

Command I am running is below

```
sudo ./concourse worker   \
--work-dir worker   \
--tsa-host <ip_address>   \
--tsa-public-key host_key.pub  \
--tsa-worker-private-key worker_key \
--garden-dns-proxy-enable \
```

However, I get the following error as address is already in use

```
Exit trace for group:
garden exited with error: Exit trace for group:
dns-proxy exited with error: listen udp :53: bind: address already in use
garden-runc exited with nil

baggageclaim exited with nil
beacon exited with nil
```

On further investigation by running `$ sudo lsof -i :53` I discovered that port is already in used by dnsmasq

```
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
dnsmasq 3239 nobody    4u  IPv4  30745      0t0  UDP WCI:domain 
dnsmasq 3239 nobody    5u  IPv4  30746      0t0  TCP WCI:domain (LISTEN)
```

Worker is running on Ubuntu 16.04 and concourse binary is v3.4.0

I appreciate your help in resolving this.